# file stop read when line reached

Tags: rebol

I have the code below to begin read the rest of the file after I have found the line containing the string "start"

```
   foreach line clines [
      if find [%start] line [
      print line
     ]
   ]
```

I can't figure it out from the documentation.. what's going on here? seems logical to me.

Comment: Hello... and welcome.  Please use the "edit" button to update your question to include a *complete* example with your input and desired output, and enough of the program so others can reproduce any behavior you find puzzling.  See ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Regarding answers that are not in your language tag being shown by the suggestions, I'm sure the tag is weighted but Rebol only has about 500 questions.  If you want to discuss that kind of issue there is [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) *(vs in the question)*

Comment: Note also that niftily... [StackOverflow retains history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30605407/revisions), should you need information back that you or others have edited out.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have always to read the file before you can search in the content of the file.

Maybe you are looking for something like

```
clines: read/lines %myfile
found: false
foreach line clines [
    if any [
        found 
        found:  find line "start"
    ]  [
        print line
    ]
]
```

an other way would be

```
cfile: read %myfile
print all [
    cfile: find cfile "start"
    find/tail cfile lf
]
```